# Why does Rails have number_to_delimited and number_with_delimiter two different helper methods with the same functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why do `ActiveSupport::Helpers.number_to_delimited` and `ActionView::Helpers.number_with_delimiter` have different names while there are methods, like `number_to_percentage`, keep the same name in both helper modules?

Answer (score 0):

`number_with_delimiter` is using the number_to_delimiter under the hood.

```
# File actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb, line 206
def number_with_delimiter(number, options = {})
  delegate_number_helper_method(:number_to_delimited, number, options)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this part. I want to know if there's any reason these two methods have different names. Because there're methods like number_to_percentage who keep the same name